# longblob base64 image from db

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I am getting my image as a longblob from my mysql database, I got a bit of my code for you. This works in chrome but in IE8 the image do not render properly, or the img cannot be found.

```
 <div class="car-image"><a href="carinformation.php?id='.$row["id"]. '"><img width="500px" height="200px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($row["picture"]). '" />';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't like data URLs that are over 32k characters long. Is your URL longer than that?

Comment: @Anicho: IE9 apparently doesn't have an arbitrary length limit.

Comment: It seems this is the issue, IE9 shows it but it messes up css rendering but there are work arounds for that.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same logic and succeeded in IE 8.

Did you use `base64encode` for `base64encoded` string?

Comment: I'm sorry about my bad English.  
I would like to say "I guess you did base64encode twice."  
I used to do like"INSERT INTO var (picture) VALUES (".base64_encode($data).");"